# Which drivers to use for AMD Kaveri APU for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xorg, 16.04, amd-graphics

I just managed to install Ubuntu 16.04 using nomodeset through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu?lq=1) method. But now when I see in software & updates-->additional drivers, it shows unknown:unknown the device is not in use. What should I install/do now to make full use of my APU ? I read about how you should not install any proprietary drivers in Ubuntu 16.04 but in my case I don't even have any by default. Are there any xorg drivers I am supposed to be using ?

Comment: Please run sudo lshw and copy the entire result into paste.ubuntu.com and insert a link to it into your question. Also add a screenshot of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Read this with reference to AMD and Ubuntu 16.04 [HERE](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have been through that article already but I dont understand how to use the open-source AMDGPU or the open-source Radeon driver in place of flgrx for my AMD APU Kaveri. I checked out their websites but still cant figure out how or which drivers to install. Can you please help with some terminal commands ? or any method to install them.